# Send programs from ubuntu partition to mint partition

Tags: system, transfer

To begin sorry for my bad English (I speak french).

I had some problems from my Ubuntu system and for this I'm going to install Ubuntu mint on another partition to keep safe my data...
And I want to transfer some of my program from Ubuntu to mint, because I can't have internet all time (~500Gb of games and programs).

Is this possible?

I know with some terminal commands its possible du "update" installed programs list, but to transfer i don't know how to do.
I had try to copy the /use folder but the boot failed etch time when I used Debian

Thanks before :)

Comment: Nope. Not possible. Maybe we can help you with the problems you've had in Ubuntu. Do not hesitate to post a question.

Answer (score -1):

1. Do you have a separate /home partition under Ubuntu installation?
2. If yes, then install Linux Mint normally and direct it to use the /home as new /home (Don't format the partition)
3. If no, you can install Mint normally and mount the Ubuntu partition in your Mint file manager and use as is, no need to transfer data. You can copy-paste anything anywhere as per your requirement
4. For program transfers, your packages are stored in /var/cache/apt/archives/ (unless you cleaned it with apt-get clean), copy those .deb files to the Desktop of your Mint installation (use sudo for permission), then in Mint use 'sudo dpkg -i /home/Desktop *.deb'
5. For more info: https://superuser.com/questions/378686/when-you-do-apt-get-install-where-are-the-deb-files-stored

Hope it helps, thanks

Comment: I think 4 and 5 are bad ideas. First those .deb files are not the installed programs. Second, many of them will be Ubuntu specific, and may not install cleanly.

Comment: Thanks for the concern Mike, although, 4 and 5 are not my idea, it came from someone in the mentioned web link, somehow, this thing proved to be beneficial to him. You may refer to the page. And, as long as, Linux Mint is concerned, it's directly based on Ubuntu with a few mint specific settings and packages I believe as them http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2059684

Comment: So, apparently, you've not tested any of it, and do not know if it works in this particular case. The answer does come from you here, also note that the question you've quoted is very different, as it does not include switching distros or 'sending programs'.

Comment: Copying .deb files had been a practice of me long time ago, when I had dial-up connection. I tested that with Ubuntu installations. Even now, I have such copies available with me in an external HDD to use with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but I don't use that version now. Although, I successfully did install a few Debian 7 packages on Crunchbang 11, like Darktable, Wine, etc.

Comment: Thank, but for the packages installed how can I do?

Comment: Please see point 4 and 5. Use a USB drive to copy from Ubuntu and then paste on Mint desktop. Don't copy the /archives folder, but .deb files in it. Paste them on desktop without creating a folder. Rest, use the command.